# i am trying to read a text file in visual basics but i am not able to store the details in the array it gives errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Dim EmpId(100) As String
Dim Lastname(100) As String
Dim firstname(100) As String
Dim hrs(100) As Integer
Dim min(100) As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'declare variables  
    Dim result As DialogResult 'what did the user choose in the open dialog (open or cancel)
    Dim strFileName As String 'store file path of the selected file
    Dim strRecord As String
    Dim sreStreamReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strFieldValues(100) As String 'to store extracted field values.

    Try
        result = filebrowser.ShowDialog
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            strFileName = filebrowser.FileName
            'create a StreamReader object by opening the file for input
            sreStreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(strFileName)

            counter = 0
            i = 0
            Do While sreStreamReader.Peek() <> -1
                strRecord = sreStreamReader.ReadLine()
                strFieldValues = strRecord.Split(",")
                EmpId(counter) = strFieldValues(i) & firstname(counter) = strFieldValues(i) & Lastname(counter) = strFieldValues(i) _
                & hrs(counter) = strFieldValues(i) & min(counter) = strFieldValues(i)
                counter = counter + 1
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 0 To j < counter Step +1
                Label1.Text = EmpId(j) & firstname(j) & Lastname(j) & hrs(j) & min(j)
            Next





        sreStreamReader.Close()
        End If
    Catch exFile As IO.FileNotFoundException
        'processed when the file cannot be found            
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot locate the file.", _
            "FileopenDialog", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
            MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        '  Catch ex As Exception
        'handles any other errors            
        '   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "FileopenDialog", _
        '    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to give enough information to allow people to answer it.

Comment: `For j = 0 To j < counter` is not valid syntax for vb.net.

Comment: You are just overwriting the text property of the label, again and again in this For loop. What do you expect to see in the label?

Comment: Since i and counter hold the same value why use 2 variables?

Comment: `EmpId(counter) = strFieldValues(i) & firstname(counter) = strFieldValues(i) & Lastname(counter) = strFieldValues(i) _
                & hrs(counter) = strFieldValues(i) & min(counter) = strFieldValues(i)` This line makes no sense at all. Back to the books.

Comment: You can't throw several assignment statements into the middle of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your text file would look like this if opened in notepad.

```
1,Smith,Mary,7,45
2,Jones,Bill, 8,15
3,Mathew,Mark,6, 20
4,Luke,John,9,30
```

Notice there are no spaces. If there are spaces you may have to use .Trim on the strings.

I have a class called `Employee`. In the class there is a custom constructor (the `Sub New`) which sets all the appropriate properties. The values will come from the text file as you will see in a minute.

Then in the buttton click event a list of the type `Employee` is created.

```
Dim EmpList As New List(Of Employee)
```

It can hold objects of the type Employee. I use a `List(0f T) instead of an array because I don't have to know ahead of time how many lines are in the file.

The `.ReadAllLines` method of the `File` object returns an array containing each line in the file as an element of the array. Loop through the lines array calling `.Split` on each line which returns an array presumably containing each of the fields you are interested in. Each element is sent to the constructor of Employee and the resulting new Employee is added to the list. If there are extraneous spaces in the file this is where you may need to call `.Trim` to get rid of them

Finally, I have added a DataGridView to the form at design time. Set the .DataSource property to the list of employees and your data is displayed in the grid with headers.

```
Public Class Employee
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property LasName As String
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property Hours As Integer
    Public Property Minutes As Integer

    Public Sub New(iden As String, lname As String, fname As String, hr As Integer, mn As Integer)
        ID = iden
        LasName = lname
        FirstName = fname
        Hours = hr
        Minutes = mn
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim EmpList As New List(Of Employee)

    Try
        Dim result = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog
        If Not result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            MessageBox.Show("No file selected")
        End If
        Dim strFileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFileName)
        For Each line In lines
            Dim strFieldValues = line.Split(","c)
            EmpList.Add(New Employee(strFieldValues(0), strFieldValues(1), strFieldValues(2), CInt(strFieldValues(3)), CInt(strFieldValues(4))))
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = EmpList
    Catch exFile As IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot locate the file.", "FileopenDialog", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey...that code helped me thankss..but i want to know will i be able to use that array type data for further calculation like i want to calculate weekly wages from the five files....

Comment: hey i tried to figure out what you said but i am not able to figure out of how to analyze data for example i would like to multiply time with 9.5..can you help please..

Comment: @RonilKumar Ask a new question. Show your best attempt at coding the multiplication. You still haven't accepted my answer.